# Animated Image animationRepeatCount CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a pretty neat animation that basically draws out a border for a collection view cell.

I have the animation working well, I'm unable to keep it from repeating indefinitely.

In: `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {`

I have set up the cell this way:

```
var image = UIImage.animatedImageNamed("Shape + Oval ", duration: 0.5)

    cell.cellImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    cell.cellImageView.image = image
```

Why is `animationRepeatCount` not stopping my cell images from continually looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed two different methods of animating an image in a `UIImageView` - You are supplying an animated `UIImage` but then trying to control the animation via the `UIImageView` properties.

Rather than using an animated `UIImage`, you should create an array of `UIImage` objects and use this to set the `animationImages` property of the `cell.imageView`.  You can then control the duration via `cell.imageView.animationDuration` and `cell.imageView.animationRepeatCount`